# How can I create a file when file path name is over 255 characters using MFC in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am working in Windows,using vc++2010 and MFC.

Following is my code:

```
CFile File;
TCHAR lpCause[1024];
CFileException eException;
CString strErrorMessage;
//  a very long file path name means a file name over 255 characters
if (!File.Open(_T("a very long file path name"), CFile::modeCreate, &eException))
{
    eException.GetErrorMessage(lpCause, 1024);
    strErrorMessage = lpCause;
}
else
    File.Close();
```

When I run the code, I got error message:"a very long file path name contains an incorrect path".

My questions are:

1. How to modify my code to make it work?
2. I learn that `CreateFile()` function can add `"\\\\?\"` in the beginning of file path, then it will extend this limit to `32767` wide characters.How can I do the same thing in MFC?

Comment: `CFile` is just an abstraction over the standard Windows API. Somewhere down below there will be a call to `CreateFile`. And remember that all backslashes in string literals needs to be escaped.

Comment: also only `CreateFileW` can use long paths. `CreateFileA` hard limited to ~256 chars. so you need explicit use `W` api and `WCHAR` strings, but not `TCHAR`

Comment: Does this work: `!File.Open(_T("\\\\?\\a very long file path name")` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz , No, it can't.

Comment: @RbMm, Windows 10 dynamically allocates the buffer to decode an ANSI string, i.e. it calls [`RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlansistringtounicodestring) with `AllocateDestinationString` set. This is independent of its new long-path support, and IIRC this began in Windows 8. Of course it's just interesting trivia for now. Previous versions use a static buffer that limits conversion to `MAX_PATH`, and the documentation still requires Unicode for long, extended paths.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, now `Basep8BitStringToDynamicUnicodeString` used (long time not look for this). yearly used fixed size buffer in `TEB`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Cause

In the source of `CFile::Open()`, there is an explicit check if the path length exceeds `_MAX_PATH`:

```
if (lpszFileName != NULL && SUCCEEDED(StringCchLength(lpszFileName, _MAX_PATH, NULL)) )
```

If `_MAX_PATH` is exceeded, the function sets `pException->m_cause = CFileException::badPath` and returns `FALSE`.

This is true even for the MFC version that comes with VS2017.

So the standard technique to circumvent the `_MAX_PATH` limit, that is prefixing the path with `\\?\` won't work.

## Possible Solutions

Call `CreateFileW()` directly to pass it a path with `\\?\` prefix. Use the `CFile` constructor that accepts a `HANDLE` to manage the file through a `CFile` object. The `CFile` object will take ownership of the handle so you must not call `CloseHandle()` on the handle.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW( L"\\\\?\\a very long file path name", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nullptr, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL );
if( hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    // Manage the handle using CFile
    CFile file( hFile );
    // Use the file...

    // The CFile destructor closes the handle here. 
}
else
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    // TODO: do your error handling...
}
```

Another possibility is to derive a class from `CFile` that overrides `CFile::Open()` (which is virtual). For the implementation copy/paste the MFC source, but leave out the `_MAX_PATH` check. For a big project, this class could be a drop-in replacement for `CFile` to enable long paths. You could even go so far to prepend the `\\?\` prefix if it isn't already there (but that is more involved as the prefix also disables the regular transformations from a Win32 path to a NT-style path, like converting `/` to `\`, resolving dots and so on).

Comment: @eryksun MSFT still seems to consider this a beta feature, as the "LongPathsEnabled" registry key isn't set by default. I can't see another reason for this double-opt-in requirement.

Comment: The "Maximum Path Length Limitation" applies to the Win32 API, not to MFC.  If `CFile::Open()` still has a hard-coded check for `_MAX_PATH`, no amount of manifestation or Registry tweaking will allow longer paths to be used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is right, that was a thought error of mine. There is no branching for long-path-aware processes in the MFC code. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: To apply the `"\\\\?\\"` prefix, first normalize the path via `GetFullPathName`. If it normalizes as an extended local-device path, you're done. If it's a regular local-device path (i.e. prefixed by `"\\\\.\\"`), replace "." by "?" in the prefix. (To be completely correct, check whether it's a DOS device in an *existing* directory, e.g. `"C:\\spam\\nul.txt"` is `"\\\\.\\nul"` only if `"C:\\spam"` exists.) If it's UNC (e.g. `"\\\\server\\share\\"`), translate it to the explicit UNC device, e.g. `"\\\\?\\UNC\\server\\share\\"`. Otherwise simply prepend the prefix to the normalized path.

Comment: Thanks, I get it.